# Is merging from remote branch a bad habbit?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

We used to create a branch for each feature in our git repo. Say, I have branch `issue-2222` created by my colleague and I want to merge it to `master`. Just merge, no modifications on my side. I have two options:

1. Checkout branch `origin/issue-2222` to my local branch `issue-2222`, this will create a local branch which tracks `origin/issue-2222`. Merge *my local branch* `issue-2222` to `master` and push. Delete local and remote branches.
2. Just run `git merge origin/issue-2222`. Delete remote branch.

Which way is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should this be a bad habit?

Unless you want to do anything with the local `issue-2222` branch, there is no need to checkout this branch (i.e. create a local version of that branch) before merging to master.

Just do `git merge origin/issue-2222` and then delete the remote branch.

Things would be different if you want to do some modifications on `issue-2222` before merging into master. An example could be that you don't want to merge the branch directly but rebase it before merging. In that case you would need a local branch.